# Python: check if a number is already in a grid of list of lists

Tags: python

In Python, I'm trying to create a duplicate checker that can check if the number that I'm entering is already in the grid. If not present, it should return `False`. So for example, numbers `1, 8, 9` should return `False` and others should return `True`. Can someone help me?

```
grid = [[0, 2, 3],
        [4, 0, 5],
        [6, 7, 0]]


number_rows = len(grid)
def possible(n):
    global grid
    if number_rows == n:
        return False
    return True
    

possible(1)  # ---> True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the grid is a list of lists you can use a [for/else block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
def possible(n, grid):
    for x in grid:
        if n in x:
            return False
    else:
        return True

grid = [[0, 2, 3],
        [4, 0, 5],
        [6, 7, 0]]

print(possible(1, grid))  # ---> True
print(possible(2, grid))  # ---> False
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using packages such as NumPy, the easiest way I can think of is to use Python's `any` with list comprehension. Consider something like:

```
def possible (number, grid):
    check = [number in sublist for sublist in grid]

    return not any(check)
```

In the function, `check` will loop through the sublists and return a list of Trues and Falses depending on if `number` exist in each sublist. For instance, if you pass 2 as the `number`, `check` will be `[True, False, False]` because 2 only exist in the first sublist.

Then, the `any` function, like the name suggests, if there are any `True`s within `check`. Finally, the `not` keyword inverts it, since you want the function to return True if there are not already in the "grid".

Answer (score 0):

`number_rows = len(grid)` only counts the number of lists in the main list `grid[a,b,c]`. In your code, you're testing if the number you input is equal to the length of the main list. Use the `n in list` to test if it's true or false.

```
def possible(n):
    temp = [a for b in grid for a in b] ##put all the values from the grid into a single layer list
    if n in temp: 
        return False
    return True
```